# можно ли закодировать обычный String в json?

Tags: flutter, dart

хотел закодировать, наверное это не возможно, я об этом тоже подумал, но все же спрошу, можно ли `String` закодировать в json:

```
String str = '[{namingLine:sdasdasd,textLine:asdasdasd},{namingLine:adasd,textLine:asdasd}]';
```

что бы в итоге получилось как следуюшее:

```
[{"namingLine":"sdasdasd","textLine":"asdasdasd"},{"namingLine":"adasd","textLine":"asdasd"}]
```

дело в том что строку хочу добавить в phpmyadmin и при надобности взять от туда эту строку и вывести на экран как json файл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Закодирование string в json - называется "распарсить строку", "десеарилизовать строку".  Для этого воспользуйтесь библиотекой `dart:convert`

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var jsonData = '{ "name" : "Ivan", "age" : 30  }';
  var parsedJson = json.decode(jsonData);
  print(parsedJson['age']);
}
```

Comment: имеется в виду строка в котором нет двойных кавычек

Comment: почему Вы приняли ответ?

Comment: оказывается в string можно добавлять кавычки(типа: `String str = ' [{"a":"1","b":"1"}{"a":"2","b":"2"}] '` ), поэтому и принял, спасибо